# Unable to see Android/iOS Folder in react native project

Tags: android, ios, react-native, splash-screen

I am beginner in react-native , i am following the official website to create React-Native project .

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

This is creating the the project structure like this :

[image]

But i want to add Splash in ios and android , and i am looking at tutorials  all add the splash in the native code , why **android** and **ios**  folder in not created in My React Native project .

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Running following commands should do the trick:**

```
sudo rm -rf android/ ios/ #Delete Android and ios folders first...
react-native eject
react-native upgrade //rebuilds android/ios folders
react-native link
react-native run-android
react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

1. node -v
2. brew install node
3. brew install watchman
4. npm install -g react-native-cli
5. react-native init AwesomeProject
6. cd AwesomeProject
7. react-native run-ios or run android

This gets you the android and and iOS projects